# Отображение элементов в приложении Android

Tags: android

Я написал небольшую программу для вычисления выражений использующих множества. Но на маленьких экранах происходит следующее  [Скрин с клавиатурой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQgR4.jpg) и [без](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqFQs.jpg)
Как зафиксировать нижнюю часть?

Решил проблему добавлением в  AndroidManifest.xml строки

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

спасибо за помощь

Comment: А может для маленьких экранов сделать отдельный layout?

Comment: Так он отображает нормально, но когда активна клавиатура, нижняя часть поднимается, неужели нельзя отключить этот сдвиг?

Comment: покажи код леяута... чет ты там напутал...